# How to properly use jQuery to output html string from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My php will get a string of html from database. The retrieved string has html tags, special characters, such as double quotes and single quotes, and line break. Therefore, The string cannot be directly used by jQuery. I want to ask if there is any good solution to remove all the line break and escape those special characters dynamically? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

The text is randomly copied from another website. I am sorry that there is no code yet since I do not have any idea of how to do it. But I will use jQuery to append the html to one of the .

```
<p class="story-body__introduction">President Barack Obama stood in the White House briefing room and, once again, railed against those who object to increased firearm regulation.</p>
<p>"Right now, I can imagine the press releases being cranked out,"&nbsp;<a class="story-body__link-external" href="http://time.com/4058961/oregon-shooting-president-obama-transcript-speech/">he said</a>. "We need more guns, they'll argue. Fewer gun safety laws. Does anybody really believe that?"</p>
<p>Mr Obama cited polls that find "the majority of Americans understand we should be changing these laws".</p>
<p>A mid-July survey by the Pew Research Center<a class="story-body__link-external" href="http://www.people-press.org/2015/08/13/continued-bipartisan-support-for-expanded-background-checks-on-gun-sales/">seems to support</a>&nbsp;his claim. Almost 80% of respondents backed laws preventing the mentally ill from purchasing firearms, and 70% were in favour of a national gun-sale database.</p>
<h2 class="story-body__crosshead">So the public support it, why doesn't it happen?</h2>
<p>Those numbers don't really mean much, however. What does matter is the opinion of members of the US Congress - and that legislative body is overwhelmingly against further gun regulation.</p>
<p>This disposition of Congress is a reflection of the disproportionate power of less-populated states in the Senate, the conservative-leaning composition of the current House congressional map and a Republican primary process that makes officeholders more sensitive to vehemently pro-gun-rights voters within their party.</p>
<p>Congress doesn't have to represent the views of the majority of Americans, at least as expressed in opinion surveys. It represents the views of Americans who go at the polls on Election Day and the simple majorities in the voting districts in which they cast their ballots.</p>
```

**EDIT**

PHP function to remove line break and escape special characters:

```
public function getSingleLineHtml($html_input) {
    $output = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $html_input);
    $lines = explode("\n", $output);
    $new_lines = array();

    foreach($lines as $i => $line) {
        if(!empty($line)) {
            $new_lines[] = trim($line);
        }
    }
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(implode($new_lines), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

phtml file which output the html content:

```
<div class="content-block" id="content-block-1"></div>

<?php
    $html_content = dataFromDb['content'];
    $html_content = getSingleLineHtml($html_content)
?>

<script>
    jQuery("#content-block-1").append('<?php echo $html_content; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Put the string that you get, in the question.

Comment: Is htmlspecialchars (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) helps?

Comment: what exactly do you want jQuery to do with the code? Try have a look if jQuery.parseHTML() may help you: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: @Danilo I tried jQuery.parseHTML(), but error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" is displayed. I think it is due to the double quotes and single quotes in the string.

Comment: @AhesanaliMomin The function htmlspecialchars will also escape the html tag. As a result, the html tags are displayed as plaintext. However, the html tags should be kept.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use htmlspecialchars_decode() instead of htmlspecialchars() php function.

Comment: It does not work. I use htmlspecialchars_decode to get a string. Then, I put the string to javascript using the following way: jQuery('#element-1').append('<?php $content; ?>');    And it still returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" .

Comment: I think you should have to paste your actual full code so some one can understand clearlu

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just add the code of my phtml file to my question.

Comment: I see that your html also contains mixed string like ' and ".

Comment: If you are using ' at start use " inside every other places. If you have to use ' than you have to use escape sequence

Comment: Yes. I tried so many ways to solve the problem, such as converting the double quotes to single quotes and vice versa in the html file. However, I cannot change the quotes in the content from data. So I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: By the way why are you adding content from jquery ? Can't you print directly?

Comment: It is just a simpler version of my code. I need to use jQuery to print the content.

Comment: I think you should directly have to use php. You should not have to add extra layer of jquery to achieve your task until you require that data in jquery to perform ui tasks.